# How to delete directory containing many subdirectories from an Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I made a mistake while partitioning my parquet table in amazon s3 and I end up with a folder containing few millions of subdirectories and it will take months to delete the whole directory.  Do you have any idea how to proceed quickly?
Thanks.

I have the following folder structure in s3:

```
enter code 
my_parquet/id=1/..
my_parquet/id=2/..
....
my_parquet/id=6000000/..
```

Comment: The fastest way to proceed would be to just initiate the lifecycle-delete-magic John suggests and forget it, and meanwhile start working on a new bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **Lifecycle Policy** on the bucket, specifying the desired path.

Choose to delete the objects and they will be magically deleted sometime over a 24-hour (or so) period. It works on any number of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to delete the bucket and recreate it. Using the AWS CLI this would be `aws s3 rb s3://bucket-name --force`. This won't work if the bucket has versioning enabled. In that case you need to [empty the bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html#empty-bucket-console).

Also keep in mind that conceptually S3 doesn't really have folders/subdirectories. There are just objects, and some of them are logically grouped with prefixes in the name.

Comment: Thanks for replying !

Comment: No problem! Feel free to upvote answers that are helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use recursive delete with prefix:

```
aws s3 rm s3://bucket/my_parquet --recursive
```

Comment: If this is still too slow, then you'll want to use [@bwest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401096/bwest) answer.

Comment: Thanks  for the anwser!